# Переименовать файлы при копировании Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

Код, который по списку, находящемуся в ListBox копирует файлы в выбранную пользователем папку. В списке файлов могут находиться файлы с **одинаковыми именами**, **но находящиеся в разных директориях**.

**Как реализовать такой алгоритм:** Если файл уже существует в целевой папке, то при копировании добавить к имени файла символ "1"?

Копирование реализовано так:

```
 procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      i   : integer;
      dir : string;
    begin
      if SelectDirectory ('Выбор папки, Куда копировать:', 'D:\,C:\', dir) then
        begin

          for i := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count-1 do
            begin
              if FileExists (ListBox1.Items.Strings[i]) then
                CopyFile (PChar(ListBox1.Items.Strings[i]), PChar(dir + '\' + ExtractFileName (ListBox1.Items.Strings[i])), false);

            end;
        end;
    end;
```

Comment: @Igor, И еще один момент, так сказать для красоты списка: Можно как то эти цифры в скобки заключить (). Что бы генерация цифр была к примеру вот такого плана - Fayl(11). За поправку очень благодарна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var 
  newFile: string;
  counter: integer;
  ...

      for i := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count-1 do
      begin
        if FileExists (ListBox1.Items.Strings[i]) then
        begin
          newFile := dir + '\' + ExtractFileName(ListBox1.Items.Strings[i]);
          counter := 1;
          while FileExists(newFile) do
          begin
            newFile := dir + '\' + ExtractFileName(ListBox1.Items.Strings[i]);
            newFile := ChangeFileExt(newFile, '') + IntToStr(counter) + ExtractFileExt(newFile);
            Inc(counter);
          end;
          CopyFile (PChar(ListBox1.Items.Strings[i]), PChar(newFile), false);
        end;
      end;
```

Comment: А такой вопрос: В вашем коде, возможно: список генерации цифр, к одинаковым файлам - упорядочить. Ну к примеру по порядку 1,2,3 и так хоть до 1000. Cейчас, когда более 10 одинаковых файлов, получаются имена вот такого плана: 1234567891011121314151.txt. Это не принципиально, но по возможности помогите - исправить.

Comment: @Татьяна Пардон, это был мой прокол.

Comment: И еще один момент, так сказать -  для красоты списка: Можно как то эти цифры в скобки заключить (). Что бы генерация цифр была к примеру вот такого плана - Fayl(11). За поправку очень благодарна.

Comment: `... + '(' + IntToStr(counter) + ')' + ...`